# "Personalización de las URL por defecto de Devise: Eliminar "/new" y "/edit" y configurar una URL alternativa" Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

¿Cómo puedo personalizar las URL que utiliza por defecto Devise? Mi objetivo es eliminar "/new", "/edit" y otras partes, o configurarla para que utilice otra URL en su lugar. Por ejemplo, en lugar de "/users/sign_up/new", deseo que sea simplemente "/users/sign_up" sin el "/new".

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podes hacer es usar en tu routes.rb el método `devise_for`. Acá está la documentación del método: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper:devise_for

Si agregas esto en el routes.rb: `devise_for :users` te va a generar las siguientes rutas:

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                  {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"new"}
         user_session POST   /users/sign_in                    {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"create"}
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out                   {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"destroy"}
```

Y si necesitas otro nombre diferente a lo que te da devise (por ejemplo preferis usar `/login` en vez de `/sign_in`) podes hacer algo como esto:

```
as :user do
   get 'login', to: 'users/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
end
```

Espero te sirva!

## UPDATE

En respuesta a tu pregunta: "Pero para hacer que en vez sign_up/edit solo sea /config "

Acá te dejo la documentación de como hacerlo: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

La idea sería poner dentro de la opción **skip** el nombre del controller al cual le querés crear rutas personalizadas. En tu caso si querés editar el **sign_up/edit** tendrías que hacer algo como

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]

devise_scope :user do
  get '/config', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :edit_user_registration
  put '/config', to: 'devise/registrations#update', as: :user_registration
  delete '/config', to: 'devise/registrations#destroy'
  get '/cancel', to: 'devise/registrations#cancel', as: :cancel_user_registration
  post '/users', to: 'devise/registrations#create'
  get '/sign_up', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
end
```

Comment: Pero para hacer que en vez sign_up/edit solo sea /config

Comment: Ahí modifiqué la respuesta que te había hecho antes

Comment: Una pregunta, como se haría para la verificacion de correo como para la recuperacion de contraseña? Disculpa las molestias